# I'm using IMPORTDADA in Google sheets to get data from a csv file online but I'm getting the error, "Resource at url contents exceeded maximum size"

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to get the data from this csv file: "https://app.matrixify.app/files/vasasro/99320ce64bfe22f855ce03e71796e4db/MatrixifyAllExport.csv"

This is for product that we want to edit for vasaro.com and we need to export the data to Google Sheets automatically.

Thank you for your help.

When I tried IMPORTDADA, it worked for small files, but not for this larger file.

Answer (score 0):

When I check the CSV data of your URL, it seems that the data size is 2,413,638 bytes and 1158 rows and 93 columns. I think that this is the reason for your current issue. In this case, in order to put the values into Spreadsheet, how about using Google Apps Script?

#### Sample script 1:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Spreadsheet, and save the script. When you use this script, please put a custom function of `=SAMPLE("https://app.matrixify.app/files/vasasro/99320ce64bfe22f855ce03e71796e4db/MatrixifyAllExport.csv")` to a cell. By this, the CSV data is retrieved and put the values to the Spreadsheet. This can be used like IMPORTDATA.

```js
const SAMPLE = url => Utilities.parseCsv(UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText());
```

#### Sample script 2:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Spreadsheet, and save the script. And, please set the sheet name. In this case, please run the function `myFunction` with the script editor. By this, the CSV data is downloaded and put to the Spreadsheet.

```js
function myFunction() {
  const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set your sheet name.
  const url = "https://app.matrixify.app/files/vasasro/99320ce64bfe22f855ce03e71796e4db/MatrixifyAllExport.csv"; // This is from your URL.

  const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  const values = Utilities.parseCsv(res.getContentText());
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

#### Sample script 3:

If the CSV data is large, when Sheets API is used, the process cost can be reduced a little. In that case, [please enable Sheets API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services). And, please set the sheet name. And, please run the function `myFunction` with the script editor. By this, the CSV data is downloaded and put to the Spreadsheet.

```js
function myFunction() {
  const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set your sheet name.
  const url = "https://app.matrixify.app/files/vasasro/99320ce64bfe22f855ce03e71796e4db/MatrixifyAllExport.csv"; // This is from your URL.

  const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheetId = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName).getSheetId();
  const requests = [{ pasteData: { data: res.getContentText(), delimiter: ",", coordinate: { sheetId } } }];
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({ requests }, ss.getId());
}
```

#### References:

- [Custom Functions in Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)
- [parseCsv(csv)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#parsecsvcsv)
- [setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)
- [PasteDataRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#pastedatarequest)